# VBA chart updating returning "object support" error

Tags: vba, excel, charts

Hey I'm trying to update this chart via macro from monthly pulled data but keep running into issues after it had worked once. Syntax error?

```
With Sheets("data").ChartObjects("Chart 3")
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("b55"), Range("b55").End(xlDown))
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Range("u55"), Range("u55").End(xlDown))
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Hi" 'Range("u54")
End With
```

Could I add the `SeriesCollection` statement to the `With` block to clean it up a bit as well?

Comment: What's the exact error and on which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Sheets("data").ChartObjects("Chart 3")
```

should be

```
With Sheets("data").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart
```

The chartobject is just a container for the actual chart itself